# get 'returning' value from postgres update query in code igniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

So I have a query like the following (actually more complicated but not important to the question, so I deleted some) where I 'return' a value.

The query works fine in sql:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user_authentication
            SET failed_login_attempts = failed_login_attempts + 1,
            RETURNING failed_login_attempts";
```

But in codeigniter it returns a boolean instead of an integer. This is what should happen with codeigniter's result() function, so it's not a bug or anything, but I am just wondering if there is a work-around to get the return value from an update statement.  I know I can do a second query...

```
when I user $query->result();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain it with a CTE :

```
WITH upd AS (UPDATE user_authentication
            SET failed_login_attempts = failed_login_attempts + 1
            RETURNING failed_login_attempts
            )
SELECT * FROM upd;
```